# Python not all arguments converted during string formatting?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I've received following error when trying to execute script to copy specific file from remote server to jumphost and then to my local computer.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list_files.py", line 34, in <module>
    stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command('sshpass -p %s scp -r hostname:/directory/' + list[file_number] + ' ' + '/desired_directory' % (password))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

```py
stdin, stdout, stdeer = p.exec_command('sshpass -p %s ssh hostname ls /directory/' % (password))
for line in stdout:
    if line:
        list.append(line)
i = 0
for x in list:
    print(str(i) + '. ' + x)
    i+=1

file_number = input("Type log file number you would like to get: ")

stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command('sshpass -p %s scp -r hostname:/directory/' + list[file_number] + ' ' + '/desired_directory/downloaded_file_name' % (password))
```

I've already tried change syntax to the ${0} instead of %s but it didn't help. I assume problem is in list[file_number] not in %s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'sshpass -p %s scp -r hostname:/directory/' + list[file_number] + ' ' + '/desired_directory/downloaded_file_name' % (password)
```

Because of operator precedence, this fragment means the formatting only applies to `'/desired_directory/downloaded_file_name'`. ;)

To fix it, either put all string concatenation in parentheses or move `%` formatting to the first element only:

````
('sshpass -p %s scp -r hostname:/directory/' + list[file_number] + ' ' + '/desired_directory/downloaded_file_name') % (password)```
````

```
'sshpass -p %s scp -r hostname:/directory/' % (password) + list[file_number] + ' ' + '/desired_directory/downloaded_file_name'
```